# Struggling to call method to another class

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to programming and im trying to call a method from one class to another class. I keep getting the error, "name 'quad' is not defined.

```
class problem(object):
    def ask(problem):
        problem = input("What type of problem are you trying to solve? 
Quadratic, ").capitalize() #add more
        if problem == "Quadratic":
            quad.equation()

class quadratic(object):    
    def equation():
        a = float(input('Enter a: '))
        b = float(input('Enter b: '))
        c = float(input('Enter c: '))


e = problem()
e.ask()
quad = quadratic()
```

The code isn't completely done as I am doing things one at a time, so anything helps.

I guess my question is, is there an easier way to call the method to the other class? Or am I just doing something wrong?

EDIT:
I have since fixed my code. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is `quad` supposed to be in `problem.ask`?

Comment: Essentially I'm turning quad into the Quadratic class and from there I am trying to call to the equation function.

Comment: It looks like `quadratic.equation` should be a `staticmethod`, as it doesn't rely on an instance of the `quadratic` class.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod